# What kind of image does "Psionic Image" create?

Tags: dnd-4e

[Psionic Image](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/power.aspx?id=12405):

> Effect: Each target sees the image of a Small or smaller object in your hand or in a square in the burst. The image lasts until the end of your next turn.

Given a [pixie](http://wizards.com/dnd/Article.aspx?x=dnd/4pr/20111007) who is 6" to 1' tall, creating the image of a cardboard box in a square in the burst, can the pixie hide in that image?

In a more generalized form: what is the nature of the image created?

The fluff suggests that the manifester is planting the image in the minds of surrounding people. This therefore suggests that the image appears real or, at the very least, acts to occlude the square.

How should this work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If a player of mine were to try to pull something like this I would probably allow it. It's inventive and fun and that should be rewarded.

Psionic Image is a Psionic Power that is akin to an illusion. It creates an image with no actual substance. The object looks real until touched. Then it becomes clear that it isn't.

If a being as tiny as you suggested used this power to hide itself or if a party member were to cover, say, a small porthole with a Psionicly Imaged piece of canvas, I would give a bonus of 2-5 to their stealth check for being hidden (how much of a bonus would be based on how inventive/appropriate it is to the situation and whether or not the party has been abusing the power for bonuses). Prolonged scrutiny of the image could show things like sand, dust bunnies or flies moving through it. That would be enough to tip the little Psionic's hand. Also, the image in no way stops sounds from traveling through it so breathing, talking, sounds from armor, etc. could be heard.

Comment: This is exactly how I would rule it as well. This power is the same as an illusion spell. Looks completely real, only close observation reveals otherwise.